# C# CMD input validation

Tags: c#, loops, validation, cmd

I'm trying to make it so that when a number is entered my program will not crash, which this does so far. Then I want it to re ask for an input until the correct charcter type is enetered.

```
int firstNum;
int Operation = 0;

   switch(Operation)
   {
        case 1:
            bool firstNumBool = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out firstNum);
         break;
   }
```

Comment: You would need to wrap your logic in a loop, I would suggest a `while loop` on each execution of the loop, check if the `Console.ReadLine()` value is equal to the character and if so, terminate the loop

Comment: @RyanWilson I get I need some sort of loop but idk how to code it, like while (firstNum != int) { int.tryparse(Console.readline())?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decompose your solution; *extract a method* for inputing an integer:

```
 private static int ReadInteger(string title) {
   // Keep on asking until correct input is provided
   while (true) {
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
       Console.WriteLine(title);

     if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
       return result;

     Console.WriteLine("Sorry, not a valid integer value; please, try again.");
   }
 }
```

And then use it:

```
 int firstNum;

 ...

 switch(Operation)
 {
      case 1:
          firstNum = ReadInteger("First number");
          break;

      ...
```